# Prevent "rm -rf"

Tags: linux, rm

As you know, "something" happened to Gitlab today and that reminds me of a question in my previous interview. I was asked "Is there any possible way to prevent the admin from using the command 'rm -rf' ? " Actually I don't know the answer, so do you guys have any ideas?
(here 'prevent' means , you have already typed in 'rm -rf' and pressed Enter  but the 'rm -rf' doesn't work. I forgot to ask the answer at the end of my interview >.<

Comment: AFAIK you can't "prevent the admin" from doing anything, that's the idea of admin - they have all the permissions...

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I'm always happy to be proven wrong and learn new things, can you add links to sources that explain how it's done ?

Answer (score 2):

You can put an alias in her environment that redefines `rm` to `rm -i`. She can override this using `'rm'`, but that takes thought.

Comment: You mean the admin can also do the same thing with "rm rf"? without a '-' ?

Comment: The new `rm` could simply be a script that checks for danger and if not found, passes all parameters on to the real rm.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'll try to explain that superuser is an administrative role for which all permission checks are normally disabled.  Of course you can enforce some countermeasures to avoid the `root` account to bypass them and account for disaster.  The first (available on many systems) is to mount the root filesystem read-only.  You can mount another filesystem read write and move there all files allowed to be modified, by means of symbolic links.  This makes the system more robust-against-mistakes, but more difficult to manage (preparing a system to work like this requires a fine grain tool to reviste and audit for flaws or inconsistencies)  The next step is disallowing administrator physical access to the system.  Rebooting a system allows you to control the booting process and to force booting from a different filesystem kernel or use a different account management database, that allows you to bypass the normal security of the system.  Another way is to manage all roles in your system to work in a non-privileged user level and completely disallow the access to the `root` account by a normal user (this approach is followed in the android system, a derivative of the linux system)  This approach has the added problem of being risky, as you can easily completely lock your system, if not carefull.

There are unix flavours that allow restricted instances of the `root` account by restricting the access to some system parts via de use of the *jail* concept.  BSD unix systems use this approach as some intent of providing a lite-virtual environment.  In this approach, you can provide a *virtual space* in your system and provide it with superuser privileges, while protecting the host system to be compromised.  It allows the superuser to create and manage even different new IP addresses and low level access to some devices.  And you can control from the host system in run time (you can navigate the guest system, without the users on it seeing your processes, the host users or the host processes)

But if the administrator has physical access to the system, nothing impedes her to `shutdown` and reboot it with a different root partition overcoming all these barriers.  Then, she can erase whatever she wants (even for encrypted volumes, whose purpose was to impede users to bypass permissions access she can overwrite them with new data, destroying the original)

Finally, as a conclusion, you'll find that *being careful and never using the `root` account for normal ordinary tasks* is the best approach.  As has been suggested by other responses, making an `alias rm='rm -i'` as some kind of security net, is normally the best way to solve the problem, as the other alternatives require better (if not best) administration skills than just forcing the `rm` command to ask you for confirmation on every file you ask it to erase.

Comment: Your last thought, never be root for ordinary work, is windowish/microsoftish. Even without being root, I can do `rm my_very_important_documents/*`. What is more dangerous: deleting my documents or delete whole /bin/*? The `alias` idea is better.

Comment: @linuxfan, your comment is valid nowadays, but not when unix was invented... Then, all user accounts happened to be in the same filesystem, sharing resources, and just one administrator's mistake could lead to sink the whole system down (all users' data is more important than only one's)  That principle comes from the seventies (believe me, I have passed several days trying to recover a system with more than 100 accounts, by its administrator's mistake) when unix was in large use, and Microsoft's Windows had not yet seen the light.  It's valid always you share a computer between several users.

Comment: 1/2 I agree only partly with you. A root user should always double-check what he is doing. But a normal user should also double-check, because it is tricked into thinking he can do no harm. The real problems are the user interface and the fact that you can not undo certain changes. The Trash bin is a great invention, as it was the VAX-VMS "automatic versioning of files" (;1 ;2 ;3 and so on). Is it possible that, in year 2017, we can do "rm *", without a way to undo the change? The interactive "rm -i", maybe forced by an alias, is just a very little step ahead...

Comment: 2/2 ...but in these days users do confirm easily without even understanding what is going on, confident that the system is "user-friendly". But unix is not. In this context, I see little difference in protecting "the system" or "protecting my documents", instead I would say that system files are less important than my documents. By not being root I only protect the system, which is exactly what you see on a windows desktop, where by default you can not even see the content of C:\program files...

Comment: @linuxfan, nope, you are misintepreting my sayings.  I haven't said an admin must work without double checking what he is doing.  I have said an admin must not work as an admin when he is doing a normal user's work.  Normally everyone must work double checking what he is doing.  The trash bin is a great invention, up to the time when you inadvertidly move the mouse and place all the `/etc` files in the `/var` directory and the system hangs on your nose (this is a real case that happened to me, sure)  Fortunately it happened with a system just installing, and doing administrator tasks, ...

Comment: but errors pay double when you commit them as an administrator.  As a user, you can break your data, but you cannot break the systematic backup and you can get your lost data from the backup.  As an administrator, you can lose everithing...

Comment: @linuxfan, by the way, I'm not a windows user, I have been using and administering unix, hp-ux, sunos, aix, tandem-nonstop-ux, digital-unix, freebsd, openbsd, SCO-unix and linux since 1987 (well, that's not ok for linux) and the experience described above is only one of the many i can relate.

Comment: I said one of your thoughts was windowish, not you, and I respect your great experience in several flavours of unix. The OP question was about "rm -rf", not about "mv /etc /var", so the alias idea is better than general advises about "don't be root" and so on. I repeat - there are enough resources to implement an undo feature in operating systems, all the stupid apps have it, why not an OS?

Comment: Not, the OP question was about *preventing root doing things like `rm -rf`*.

Comment: Sorry @LuisColorado, I really don't see the word _"like"_ in the OP question. It seems to me that he only speaks about "rm -rf". Anyway, it's better we stop to comment.

Comment: So, my answer is more general, as it covers the case of `rm -rf` and more. You should be glad of getting general responses.  Are you trying to discuss despite of anything?

Answer (score 0):

You might use (on *some* filesystems, such as [*ext4*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)) [chattr(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html) e.g. as `chattr -R +i` *dirname* (but the sysadmin could still revert that ...).

But I don't think it is a good idea. `rm -rf` should work as intended (but you might make `rm` become some `alias` e.g. in your `~/.bashrc`). Of course you have backups.

If you run `rm -rf` and interrupted it *quickly* you might try to repair your *ext4* file system using [debugfs(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html). Use carefully.

Comment: A user with admin privileges won't be able to run `chattr` and revert it? further, isn't it like `chmod` ?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful no, can you please post a link ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanism, albeit very partial, that can help about the effects of "rm -rf". By making a hard link of a file, residing in a different directory, the file can no more be deleted by a single "rm" executed in the original directory: it will disappear from the original dir, but it will continue to exist in the filesystem.

For files inside an important directory these hard links can help; unfortunately directories themselves don't support hard links (and for good reasons); so, a "rm -rf" operated on a "backupped tree via hardlinks" would destroy the directory structure too, in addition to make the files disappear from their original location. But, a carefully planned hardlink system would give a last chance to recover the lost files.